# Why not include the energy exerted by the pitcher in a kinematics problem of a flying baseball?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I solved the question below using the principle of conservation of energy. Namely, i calculated that
$$\text{KE}(i)+ (\text{Friction} \times \text{Displacment})(\cos 180) = \text{KE}(f) \, .$$
I found some logical answers and I assume that I am right. However, i'm still confused as to why we don't include the work that the pitcher exerts in the equation. Is it because we assume that that is in the past and the frame of reference we are examining is simply the ball moving from $x = 0$ to $x = 20$ (i.e. the work done by the pitcher is not part of the time frame examined)?

> A baseball of mass 145 g leaves a pitcher’s hand at 150km/hr, but due to
>   constant air resistance, it arrives at home plate 20.0m away traveling at
>   145km/hr Assume that the magnitude of the ball’s acceleration is constant
>   and that the ball travels in a straight line (ignore gravity). How much work
>   is done by friction during the flight of the ball? What is the magnitude of the
>   force of air resistance?

Comment: the work done by the pitcher is what caused the ball to be at 150km/h in the first place, so basically when you consider the kinetic energy of the ball relative to that speed, that is the effect of the energy applied by the pitcher

Answer (score 2):

> Is it because we assume that that is in the past and the frame of reference we are examining is simply the ball moving from x=0 to x=20? (i.e. the work done by the pitcher is not part of the time frame examined).

Yes, this is correct.

If you want to include the pitcher then the steps are:

1. the ball starts stationary (in the pitcher's hand)
2. the pitcher does work on the ball and increases its kinetic energy
3. the ball does work on the air, due to the aerodynamic drag, and decreases its kinetic energy

By answering as you have you are just considering step 3, which is a perfectly good way to address the problem.